# GNU Screen: Can't stuff commands unless the screen is attached?

Tags: bash, shell, script, gnu-screen

I have the following script

```
screen -d -m -S $1                #start screen minimized
screen -S $1 -X stuff "$beast     
"                                 #stuff commands
```

unless I attach the screen first it seems the affects of stuff won't do anything?
Why is this and how can I modify this script so I don't need to attach the screen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you start a Screen session in detached mode (`screen -d -m`), no window is selected, so input later sent with `screen -X stuff` is just lost. You need to explicitly specify that you want to send the keystrokes to window 0 (`-p 0`). This is a good idea anyway, in case you happen to create other windows in that Screen session for whatever reason.

```
screen -S "$1" -p 0 -X stuff "$beast$(printf \\r)"
```

(`printf \\r` to strictly emulate the <kbd>Return</kbd> key; many but not all programs accept a newline (`\n`).)

Comment: Thanks! it works perfect. Sorry everyone for being off topic

Comment: does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This recently came up while trying to answer [a question on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13953/1925).

The summary is that screen does not have a default selected window unless you attatch, but Gilles showed us how you can [force one to be selected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen/13961#13961) by adding the argument `-p 0` to your screen command.

Personally [I recommend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen/13954#13954) switching to `tmux`. Here is how you would port your screen commands to work in tmux:

```
tmux new-session -d -n $1
tmux send-keys -t $1 "$beast\n"
```